# laravel route grouping by with dynamic subdomain and without subdomain

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-5.6

I’m working on a laravel multitenant application with the support of hyn multitenant ( https://laravel-tenancy.com/ ),
all i want to show my homepage if the url is "http://domain.test" and show user(tenant-a dynamic name for each user) homepage if the url is "http://tenant.domain.test" in laravel5.6

I’ve tried

```
//enter to this group if subdomain is present and show user homepage

    Route::domain('{tenant}.domain.test')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomePage');
        Auth::routes();
    });

//else show main homepage

    Route::domain('domain.test')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomePage');
    });
```

but the problem is this require to pass the value for {subdomain} in every views else get an error like

> Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login].

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::domain(checkDomain())->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "You are on a custom domain";
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
     return "You are on main domain.";
});

public function checkDomain()
{
    if (request()->getHttpHost() == 'domain.test') {
        return request()->getHttpHost();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am expecting a wildcard subdomain routing  like if (request()->getHttpHost() == '*.domain.test')                                             thanks

Comment: in your suggestion     
Route::domain(checkDomain())->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "You are on a custom domain";
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
     return "You are on main domain.";
});

public function checkDomain()
{
    if (request()->getHttpHost() == '*.domain.test') {
        return request()->getHttpHost();
    }
}